# Next-PWA Install popup is not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, next.js, progressive-web-apps

I have built a Next.js application. Now, for PWA I am using Next-PWA library:
https://yarnpkg.com/package/next-pwa

I am able to see the install pop-up message only on my desktop's Google Chrome. I want it to work on mobile devices as well

This is my manifest.json file which I have kept in public folder.

```
{
    "name": "APP NAME FULL",
    "short_name": "APP NAME",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/favicon.ico",
            "sizes": "48x48",
            "type": "image/ico"
        },
        {
            "src": "/images/clubicon.png",
            "sizes": "200x200",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ],
    "theme_color": "#FFFFFF",
    "background_color": "#FFFFFF",
    "start_url": "/",
    "display": "standalone"
}
```

this is my next.config.js file:

```
const withPwa = require('next-pwa');

module.exports =
  withPwa(
    {

// other configs...
      pwa: {
        dest: 'public',
        register: true,
        scope: '/',
        disable: false,
        register: true,
      }
    })
```

[this is the chrome dev tool showing service worker status.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrbdD.png)

Comment: OR can I pop that add to home screen menu manually?

Comment: how did you solve yours?